# How to create a encrypted Zip file with Apache Commons Compress?

Tags: java, zip, php-ziparchive, apache-commons-compress

I use Apache Common Compress in my file manager app in android, but i can not find any example or document about creating encrypted file. Can some one help me please!

Comment: Please provide us with code samples of what you tried until now. That way we can help you more effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the "known limitations" page (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/limitations.html):

ZIP:

- no support for encryption or multi-volume archives

Comment: Do you know any Java library to compress/extract all common archive file types with password option?

Comment: It's quite late, but it's available, here: https://search.maven.org/artifact/de.idyl/winzipaes/1.0.1/jar

Comment: Another lib: https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j